# angular2 form invalid property in hidden field

Tags: angular

I have form object `"formObject"` and i want to have a `form.invalid` in formObject.isFormValid variable.

any help is appreciated.

```
export class formObject{

public isFormValid:boolean ;
.. other fields

}

<form #my-form="ngForm" >
<input type="hidden" [(ngModel)]="formObject.isFormValid" value="my-form.invalid"/> {{my-form.invalid}}
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Setting `value` attribute does not trigger change for input and model is not updated. You have to use another way to update `formObject.isFormValid`.

Comment: ya i figured that out. any other potential solution ?

Comment: Only hackish approach `value="formObject.isFormValid = my-form.invalid"`, declarative forms sadly dont have any event for validation, at least i could not find any.

Comment: i worked around and setting value on keyup now. thanks for pointing out